# Groovy: Ambiguous method overloading for method

Tags: groovy, lambda, closures

I'm struggling with `groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Ambiguous method overloading for method` exception in groovy-2.4.7.

I have 3 functional interfaces:

```
interface NoArg {
   Object handle();
}
interface OneArg {
   Object handle(Request req);
}
interface TwoArg {
   Object handle(Request req, Response rsp);
}
```

There is an App.java which provides some `overloaded` methods like:

```
public class App {
  void get(String pattern, NoArg handler) {
    ...
  }
  void get(String pattern, OneArg handler) {
    ...
  }
  void get(String pattern, TwoArg handler) {
    ...
  }
}
```

From Java I can make calls like:

```
{
  get("/", () -> "OK");
  get("/", req -> "OK");
  get("/", (req, rsp) -> rsp.send("OK"));
}
```

It works perfectly in Java, but I got an `Ambiguous method overloading for method` in Groovy when I just try:

```
{
   get("/", {-> "OK"})
}
```

Here is the full stacktrace:

`21:34:13.502 [ERROR] [system.err] groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Ambiguous method overloading for method app.App#get.
21:34:13.502 [ERROR] [system.err] Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [class java.lang.String, class app.App$_closure1] due to overlapping prototypes between:
21:34:13.502 [ERROR] [system.err]   [class java.lang.String, interface app.NoArg]
21:34:13.502 [ERROR] [system.err]   [class java.lang.String, interface app.OneArg]
21:34:13.502 [ERROR] [system.err]   [class java.lang.String, interface app.TwoArg]`

Am I missing something? Or this isn't supported in Groovy?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing an [extension module](http://www.groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#_extending_existing_classes):

```
/**
 * Example on how to hack Groovy so we can use groovy closure on script routes.
 */
class AppExtension {

  private static Object toHandler(Closure closure) {
    if (closure.maximumNumberOfParameters == 0) {
      NoArg handler = { closure() }
      return handler
    } else if (closure.maximumNumberOfParameters == 1) {
      OneArg handler = { req -> closure(req) }
      return handler
    }
    TwoArg handler = { req, rsp -> closure(req, rsp) }
    return handler
  }

  static void get(App self, String pattern, Closure closure) {
    self.get(pattern, toHandler(closure));
  }

  static void post(App self, String pattern, Closure closure) {
    self.get(pattern, toHandler(closure));
  }
}
```

I created a generic `get` method that accepts a `Closure`. Then I checked for closure parameters and convert the closure to the required interface.

Answer (score 5):

You will need to cast it to `NoArg` there is no implicit conversion to interface (like with the Java lambdas)

Example:

```
class Request{}

class Response{}

interface NoArg {
   Object handle();
}
interface OneArg {
   Object handle(Request req);
}
interface TwoArg {
   Object handle(Request req, Response rsp);
}

public class App {
  void get(String pattern, NoArg handler) {
    println(handler.handle())
  }
  void get(String pattern, OneArg handler) {
    println(handler.handle(new Request()))
  }
  void get(String pattern, TwoArg handler) {
    println(handler.handle(new Request(),new Response()))
  }
}

def app = new App()
app.get('/', {'NoArg'} as NoArg)
app.get('/', {req->'OneArg'} as OneArg)
app.get('/', {req,res -> 'TwoArg'} as TwoArg)
```

Will print

```
NoArg
OneArg
TwoArg
```

Check it out: https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/edit/6196672648445952

Comment: Thanks! but forgot to mention want to avoid cast